# How can you redirect to custom page after subscribe to NEWS LETTER

Tags: magento-2.1, newsletter

I want to redirect to new page after clicking to subscribe button. Can anyone help me over here.

Comment: After subscribing with a popup or just when the user puts the email in a textbox where they can subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to a new page by creating an interceptor. Follow these steps:

1. Create registration.php file at this location:

   ```
   app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/
   ```
2. Add this code to the registraton.php file:

   ```
   <?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'Stack_NewsletterRedirect',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```
3. Create the module.xml at this location:

   ```
   app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/etc
   ```
4. Add these codes to the module.xml file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
       <module name="Stack_NewsletterRedirect" setup_version="0.1.0"/>
   </config>
   ```
5. Now, you have to define the interceptor for
   Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction at this location:

   `app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/etc/frontend/di.xml`
6. Add these lines to di.xml file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction">
           <plugin name="redirect_after_newslettter" type="Stack\NewsletterRedirect\Plugin\Subscriber\Redirect"/>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
7. Add these codes to Redirect.php file, which is located to
   app/code/Stack/NewsletterRedirect/Plugin/Subscriber/.

   ```
       class Redirect {

           public function __construct(
           responseHttp $response, UrlInterface $url
           ) {
               $this->response = $response;
               $this->_url = $url;
           }

           public function afterExecute(\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction
   $subject, $result) {
               $url = $this->_url->getUrl('contact/index/index');
               $this->response->setRedirect($url);
               return $result;
           }

       }
   ```
8. Change contact/index/index to the URL of your custom page.
9. Finally, run the following commands:

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   ```